# sequelize error: Unhandled rejection TypeError: expecting an array or an iterable object but got [object Null]

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, bluebird

I'm trying to use findOne from sequelize in my model, but I'm receiving this error 
The table that the model is referencing is empty, how to handle this?

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: expecting an array or an iterable object but got [object Null]
```

This is my code:

```
app.get('/test/models', function(req, res) {

        var values = { 
            where: { user_id: 7 } 
        };

        MercadoLibre.findOne(values)
        .spread(function(err, meli) {

            console.log(err);

            if (typeof meli !== null) {
                console.log("undefined");
            } else {
                console.log(meli);    
            }

            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        });
    });
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few bugs in your code

- You should be handling a `Promise.reject()` result from `MercadoLibre.findOne()`.
- You should get the results of `findOne()` using `.then()`, not `.spread()`

  > `.then(function(resolve)).catch(function(reject))`

  - You *can* handle `resolve()` and `reject()` in a single `thenable`, but the format is:

    > `.then(function(resolve), function(reject))`
- You are checking for null incorrectly (no need for `typeof`), and your code will always return true (even if `meli` is `undefined`, so will the `typeof`)

  > `typeof meli !== null`

```js
app.get('/test/models', function(req, res) {
  var values = { 
    where: { user_id: 7 } 
  };

  MercadoLibre.findOne(values)
  .then(function(result) {
    // just check for false-y
    if (!result) {
      console.log('Nothing was returned!')
    }
    // redirect to the route you want
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // catch any errors
    console.log('Error, do some kind of redirect?!', err);
  });
});
```